# Oracle APEX ARP process not performed just because another process fails?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

1. You are an awesome comunity. It is the first time I couldn't find an answer for my questions and I had millions
2. Take me easy. I'm super noob and I already fell bad for making you waste your time with my dummy question
3. Soo... I'm tring to make an app with oracle apex. I have an form with an interactive report for table1. On the form page I have 3 processes in this order:

   - Automatic Row Processing (DML) that apex automaticaly made for me,
   - a pl/sql process I made and
   - the reset page process apex made.

The ARP updates, creates and deletes and is triggered by any of the buttons (SAVE, CREATE, DELETE).

My procces deletes a row in another table2 and is performed when DELETE is clicked and ITEM1 is not null (because in ITEM1 I stored the PK for the row in the second table).

The last process is the usual reset page that should clear all items value when DELETE is pressed.

Firing point is by default "Processing" for all 3.

Sometimes my process fails (and return the error I set) because of a FK constraint.

Now here is the think: If my proccess fails, the oder 2 seem not to be executed. Is that posible? If i set the condition (to be executed) of my process to Never the other 2 are working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't missing anything.

When you push a button that fires those processes, they make a *transaction*. If any of them raises an error, all of them (executed so far) are rolled back.

If you want to continue processing regardless what your own procedure (2nd one) does (I mean: whether it succeeds or not), then handle it, somehow.

A trivial (and not the best) option is to ignore possible errors, e.g.

```
begin
  delete from child_table where id = :P1_ITEM1;
exception
  when others then null;   --> ignore any errors
end;
```

Smarter way would be to intercept errors you expect. If you know (and yes, you do) that there's a possibility that foreign key constraint will be violated, check whether child rows exist; if not, delete the master row.

```
declare
  l_id child_table.id%type;
begin
  -- If row(s) with such an ID exists, L_ID will be set to that value. 
  -- In that case, don't do anything
  select m.id
    into l_id
    from child_table m
    where m.id = :P1_ITEM1
      and rownum = 1;

  -- The above query returned something; don't do anything
  null;

exception
  when no_data_found then
    -- The above query didn't return anything, so - delete a row
    delete from child_table where id = :P1_ID;
end;
```

Now, that can/could/should be modified, depending on what you really have; it is just an idea *what* to look at.

Yet another option is to set foreign key constraint to be `on delete cascade`, which means that deleting master record automatically deletes its detail records. Doing so, you wouldn't care about such a problems and your 2nd process would be as simple as

```
delete from child_table where id = :P1_ID;
```

(unless you hit another kind of an error, of course).

---

If you want to let users decide whether they want to delete rows or not, change button's action to "Redirect to URL" (currently it is "Submit", I presume). The target URL will be something like this (suppose that button's name is `P1_START_PROCESSES`):

```
javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete all rows related to this document?')){doSubmit('P1_START_PROCESSES');}
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks! But it also raises other questions 1. _all of them (executed so far) are rolled back._ What about the 3rd? After encountering an error APEX it's not even looking at the next processes? I think so but just double check. 2. I would like the user to be aware that the child will also get deleted. The first solution I can think about is to make a button that deletes both rows (I know how to do that) but only shows up on the form after the first attempt resulted that error  (don't know how to do that) What are other, maybe more elegant, solutions to let the user decide?

Comment: You're welcome. As of **1**: exactly. If any process fails, further processing is stopped. As of **2**: I edited my answer and added an example which shows how to *ask* users whether they want to continue or not.

Comment: Just adding a footnote here for posterity. Unfortunately, there are some implicit commits one must watch out for as they will end one transaction and begin a new one. This is an old (and long) post, but it may help you get a better understanding. http://www.danielmcghan.us/2012/08/implicit-commits-in-apex.html It's worth noting that `APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE` does now have a parameter to prevent the commit.